# Recommendations for Best Trimming/Edging Equipment

Tags: grass

I am interested in Stihl equipment.

I want to string trim grass, edge grass and beds w/ a blade.

For complementary, existing lawn/garden equipment, I have an electric hedge trimmer, an electric and manual pole pruner, and a Stihl backpack blower. From my experience w/ the Stihl blower I want to continue w/ Stihl equipment.

Would the Stihl KombiSystem suit my needs and if so, which model - the homeowner or one of the four professional models? Which attachments are recommended w/ the KombiSystem head to string trim grass, edge grass and beds w/ a blade?

Answer (score 1):

I like simple straight forward machines.  Having attachments, in my experience anyway, is just another thing to get lost as well as another thing to go wrong.

The only tools I use and own are; line trimmer without tap and go, just a fixed head that I can change out lengths of line, my Stihl blower and a great hydrostatic mower with extra blades to keep sharp. When purchasing equipment always get extra spark plugs and air filters and gas filters. I also used to have a great hedge trimmer, reciprocating double blades.  Got a Stihl chain saw.  I've never been happy with electric anything where I have to drag a long cord around the yard.  Way underpowered.

Be very snobbish in choosing gas and oil.  Stihl makes a great oil and get the little bottles for perfect mixing.  Never use gasoline with ethanol.  These small engines clog up quickly. I also use the star cross section for line.  Get a big roll.  I can explain how to cut, thread and balance your line.  Never have a line that is uneven, it will put lots of unnecessary stress on your engine.  Buy a great pair of safety glasses.  Never operate any equipment that rotates without glasses.  I've seen the damaged eyes!

Hand tools; Felco.  Period.  Probably the last product you'll ever find that is meant to last forever.  You should buy an extra blade or two at the same time.  I've had wonderful ratchet pole pruners and hand pruners that were able to cut 4" trees. Easy to find at any Home Show.  Get a great stone and file and learn to sharpen these blades yourself.  Scissors and by pass pruners (never go with anvil) can only be sharpened on one side.  Use silicon to clean, not WD40.

Blade trimmers for lawn edges should only be wheeled push machines, not hand held.  Blade trimmers are great for between concrete and lawn, not between plant beds and lawn.  When you get more practiced that blade edger will just gather dust.  Line trimmers do the job beautifully!  There are blade 'wackers' for brush.  You can rent those for as often as you'll need to use them.  4" trunks! Chainsaws work better.  Get to know the people at the Stihl store which hopefully also repairs equipment and carries all the parts you might need.  Stihl is my favorite brand as well...

Keep dirt out of your equipment and these wonderful tools will last forever.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a Ryobi motor and attachment system like [this](https://www.ryobitools.com/outdoor/products/list/family/expand-it).  Everything went well till the motor needed work.  Then I had no power tools till it came back from the shop, never again.